# Why it's not possible to create object attribute outside object methods?

Tags: python

While researching about python class attribute and instance attribute, I came to know that it's not possible to create object attribute outside object methods (or may be class method). Like code below will generate an "NameError" in python.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
    self.str = 'xyz'
```

Why python doesn't allow this? I'm not questioning language creator's decision, but any reason behind this. Like, is it technically incorrect or any other disadvantage of this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining a class, so there is no instance to point to outside methods. Drop the `self:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
    str = 'xyz'
```

`self` points to the *instance*, not the class. You either need to create an instance and assign directly to attributes (`test().str = 'xyz'`) *or* you need to be inside a method (when `self` can actually refer to an instance).

Comment: Does that mean a class is parsed by interpreter even before it is called or before creating any instance of that class, unlike a function where a mistake inside a function will not affect program unless that function is called?

Comment: @Alinwndrld: The interpreter creates the class object when it finds the `class` statement, yes. Add a `print` to the class body to see. Classes are objects too; you can pass around the `test` class, you can refer to the attributes defined in it, etc. In order for Python to be able to do that it needs to first execute the class body to create the class object.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is not a special name in python, you could use \

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(foo):
        foo.lst = []
```

If you want. Every method of a class gets the instance explicitly passed to it as the first parameter, you can call it whatever you want. Trying to access a parameter outside the scope of the method obviously won't work.